# Getting Invalid JWT when creating project

Tags: bentley-itwin

When I get the token from the itwin-developer-console, the below PowerShell works. However, when I generate my own token, which appears to be valid per all the parsing I do of it, I get 401 Invalid JWT. I can use the token I generate to query and manipulate work area connections with no problems as long as I provide the product-settings-service scope. I've limited the scopes to just be projects:read projects:modify like the token I get from the console, but no joy. I notice that my token does not populate entitlements. Could that be it?

```
$url = "https://api.bentley.com/projects/"

$authVal = "Bearer $($oidcClientToken.access_token)"

$today = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

$projectName = $today + " " + (Get-RandomString -Length 12 -Characters "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

$bodyCreate = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 @{
    project = @{
        displayName = $projectName
        projectNumber = $projectName
        industry = "Oil and Gas"
        projectType = "Offshore Structures"
        billingCountry = "US"
        status = "active"
        allowExternalTeamMembers = $true
    }
}

$resp5 = Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "Application/Json" -Method Post -Uri $url -Body $bodyCreate -Headers @{'Authorization' = $authVal; 'Content-Type' = 'application/json'; 'Accept' = 'application/vnd.bentley.itwin-platform.v1+json' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a different token for calling iTwin Platform APIs, please read the [Authorization documentation](https://developer.bentley.com/api-groups/administration/documentation/authorization/) on this.

Specifically in this case, the token needs to be issued by https://ims.bentley.com instead of https://imsoidc.bentley.com, which is currently used by itwin.js applications. The same client will work.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, switching the authority worked. Why is there more than one authority? Seems like an unnecessary level of complexity.

Comment: The iTwin Platform requires https://ims.bentley.com authority; iTwin.js will also use iTwin Platform APIs in their next release, so the old authority will not be used or needed any more.